# Div around YouTube video

Tags: embed, youtube, oembed

My posts have YouTube embedded videos in the form of:

```
<object width="600" height="400" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0"><param name="src" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/zN9mdItmoBs&amp;vq=hd720" /><embed width="600" height="400" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/zN9mdItmoBs&amp;vq=hd720" /></object>
```

How do I wrap a `<div>` around it?

I've tried adding the following to the `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter('embed_oembed_html', 'my_embed_oembed_html', 99, 4);
function my_embed_oembed_html($html, $url, $attr, $post_id) {
  return '<div id="video">' . $html . '</div>';
}
```

It doesn't work. What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why that's not working except maybe you need to put the returned stuff in a variable? This is what works for me when I put it in my functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'embed_oembed_html', 'tdd_oembed_filter', 10, 4 ) ; 
function tdd_oembed_filter($html, $url, $attr, $post_ID) {
    $return = '<figure class="video-container">'.$html.'</figure>';
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. I'm using Twenty Thirteen if that helps.

Comment: Michelle's code and yours works for me on WP 3.6 with no plugins installed on TwentyThirteen and any other default theme.

Comment: I'm also using WP 3.6 and no plugins; it's a fresh install. All I do is edit the functions file right? I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: How are you embedding the object? This may only work for the oembed method where you put the plaintext YouTube URL in the content on its own line and it auto-converts to an embedded object...?

Comment: I put the embed code I posted above in a post under Text.

Comment: Hmm... maybe try just embedding the link to the video on YouTube ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=zN9mdItmoBs ) ? Put it on its own line and make sure it's not linked anywhere (plaintext without an anchor link). Then when you publish the video will appear in the post. See here: http://demo.friendlyweb.us/test/ (you can log in with demo/demo to see how it looks in the page itself).

Comment: the oembed filter looks for Youtube URLs with the pattern `#https?://(www\.)?youtube\.com/watch.*#i`, pasting an object directly in the editor won't work, [see embeds in codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds).

Comment: That works, thanks. I have changed all my embed code to the link format you provided. -Michelle Thanks for the info. -Milo